# How can you distinguish an original post from a reblog in Tumblr using Python?

Tags: python, api, tumblr

I have started using pytumblr to get posts from Tumblr. My goal is to see which are reblogs and which are original posts. I tried looking at the data that the Tumblr API provides for each post, but I can't find a difference between reblogs and original posts. Also, there is not a parameter stating something like that.

I use the following function but neither the reblog_info or notes_info gives me more information.

```
blog_posts = client.posts(example_blog, notes_info=True, reblog_info=True)
```

Any insights ? Thanks.

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but it seems like you have to set the `reblog_info` flag to `True` in your request: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2

Comment: I've added some code.

Comment: Then I'm of no further use :-) Sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem. Instead of `reblog_info=True`, it needs to be `reblog_info='true'`.

Comment: Ah thanks! I had the same issue with the iOS sdk.. I was passing 1, but it accepts a string boolean value (@"true")